# Read list of urls from txt file using powershell and save each url to pdf with name from the last part of the url

Tags: powershell

The following is a powershell code to read urls from txt file and save each url to a pdf. Here   each url is saved as number.pdf. I want each pdf to be named with the last part of the url.

for ex: if a url is ' https://www.prodevelopertutorial.com/lte-chapter-1-lte-introduction/ ', I want the saved pdf file to be ' lte-chapter-1-lte-introduction.pdf '

I have obtained the code from a website. Can anybody please modify it as per my requirements.

```
$sourceFile = "D:\BATCH-PRINT-WEBPAGES-PDF\D\1\links2.txt" # the source file containing the URLs you want to convert
$destFolder = "D:\BATCH-PRINT-WEBPAGES-PDF\sharednotes\" # converted PDFs will be saved here. Folder has to exist.

$num = 0
foreach($link in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($sourceFile))
{
$num++
$outfile = $num.ToString() + '.pdf'
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' --headless --print-to-pdf="$destFolder $outfile" "$link"
Start-Sleep -s 3
}
```

From what i was able to gather around the internet, i did the following:

```
$sourceFile = "D:\BATCH-PRINT-WEBPAGES-PDF\Version 1\linktst.txt" # the source file containing the URLs you want to convert
$destFolder = "D:\BATCH-PRINT-WEBPAGES-PDF\Version 1\OP\" # converted PDFs will be saved here. Folder has to exist.

$links= Get-Content -Path D:\BATCH-PRINT-WEBPAGES-PDF\Version1\linktst.txt

$num = 0
foreach($l in $links)
{
z=[uri]'l'
$nam = z.segment[-2]
$num++
$outfile = $nam.ToString() + '.pdf'
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' --headless --print-to-pdf="$destFolder $outfile" "$link"
Start-Sleep -s 3
}
```

Its not working.

each entry in the text file is a line.

https://www.prodevelopertutorial.com/lte-chapter-1-lte-introduction/
https://www.prodevelopertutorial.com/lte-network-architecture/
https://www.prodevelopertutorial.com/4g-lte-tutorial-brief-working-of-network-elements-in-lte-architecture/
https://www.prodevelopertutorial.com/introduction-to-e-utran-network-architecture-elements/
https://www.prodevelopertutorial.com/introduction-to-epc-network-architecture-elements/

each url is in a new line in the text.

Comment: you should post what you have tried what is the error you are getting

Comment: K.  but I really do not know this. I have no knowledge in powershell scripting or object oriented languages. However I tried to do something by reading off the internet. And i will post it as an edit.

Comment: Post some sample data. Each url is in single line or comma separate value ?

Comment: each url is in a new line in the text.  I have added it as an edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Code you are using `$outfile = $nam.ToString() + '.pdf'`

You declared $nam value as 0 and increasing the number for each loop. where as files are creating with the number.

You can try below. I don't have the chrome.xe in my machine so didn't tested the outfile creation.

```
$srcfile = "E:\Workspace\Test\Test.txt"
$destloc = "E:\Workspace\Test\Dest\"

$data = Get-Content $srcfile
foreach($url in $data){
    #Write-Output $url

    $url_trim = $url.Trim()
    if($url_trim.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        $url_trim = $url_trim.Substring(0,$url_trim.Length -1 )
    }
    #Write-Host $url_trim -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $filename = $url_trim.Substring($url_trim.LastIndexOf("/")+1)
    #Write-Output $filename

    $outfile = "$filename.pdf" 
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' --headless --print-to-pdf="$destloc $outfile" "$url"
    Start-Sleep -s 3
    #Write-Output $outfile

}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm. Now say if we want the last but one part of url .. what needs to be modified here. This is asked  out of pure curiosity